# iPhone Storekit Helper Library

Tags: iphone, storekit

I have looked around for some resources relating to Apple's StoreKit framework on the iPhone and I really like the way Urban Airship's Store Front works. It is simple to use and the UI is already set up and everything. The problem is, they charge you $0.05 per download.

I have upgrades I would like to sell (basically it would download a small bit of data like an ID and "password" to access a certain feature, simply used to access content on my server), but 5 cents per download is quite a bit for what I have (I would definitely just use Store Front if I had a large file to download, but I don't).

My question is, is there something like Store Front in the sense that it manages the purchases for you but is completely self managed? Any libraries with a prebuilt UI (or even just transaction management) would be really helpful...

Thanks!

Comment: From what it sounds, you're trying to create something very simple that shouldn't take a lot of time to code yourself. Take a look at the In App Purchase Programming Guide (http://tinyurl.com/37sjmxa), it's really not that scary.

Comment: I'll take a look at the docs again. I am new to the iPhone, so it is a little bit scary for me ;)

Comment: @AndrewM Were you able to successfully integrate IAP with UrbanAirShip ? I got stuck with this error while using with Sandbox account : - paymentQueue:removedTransaction:( "<SKPaymentTransaction: 0xf6bba00>"} .Though I have configured at UA Server as well as iTunes connect.Can you pls help me with this.

Comment: No, I never ended up implementing anything with Urban Airship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jiva Devoe's [Cocoa Touch for iPhone OS 3](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470481072.html) has a chapter on Store Kit that has a lot of what you're looking for. (At $40, it's roughly equivalent to 800 downloads from Urban Airship.)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the book. Does most of the iOS 3 stuff apply to iOS 4 or is it too outdated at this point?

Comment: I would say that easily 90% of the book still applies. There's a lot of new stuff in iOS 4, but Store Kit is (mostly, if not completely) unchanged.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the link. I'll check the book out and mark this as resolved/answered for now :)